# Angular Resolvers - Using Arrays Without Observables work successfully. Why is this?

Tags: angular

When using resolvers in Angular in routing, the docs state you should use an object in the routing and and you have to use a observer in the component you need that data on activerouter.

However, in [Angular - The Complete Guide (2023 Edition)](https://www.udemy.com/course/the-complete-guide-to-angular-2/learn/lecture/14466404#search)
 (highly recommended, it is really good) it shows that you can you an array of resolvers instead objects in the router. Any by returning a promise (this.http.get()) the router will wait for the data to be fully loaded before rendering the component (without having to use an observer).

The array method (instead of objects) and without having to use a observer above works for me also. How is it this works? Why does Angular not list it in the docs?

```
  const routes: Routes = [
    {
      path: '',
      component: ReconcileMainComponent,
      resolve: [
        FooResolver,
      ],
    },
```

```js
  @Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
  })
  export class FooResolver implements Resolve<any> {
  
    constructor(
      private apiService: ApiService,
    ) { }
  
    resolve(
      route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    ) {
      return this.apiService.getApiCall();
    }
  }
```

Comment: What do you mean by “the array method”? Resolvers can resolve an observable, a promise or simply data. This is documented on the Angular site.

Comment: In the doc, they show { resolve: { hero: HeroResolver } } instead of {resolve: [HeroResolver] }. And they also imply you have to use  this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe() in the component when in the tutorial with array is was not required.

Comment: Ah got it. There are multiple ways of doing things, the tour of heroes shows a way, but the actual Angular APi docs are better to determine these kind of things. To get the resolved data also has multiple ways. If you use the snapshot, you do not have to subscribe to the route data.

Answer (score 1):

While the documentation does not mention it, the behavior somewhat makes sense, because we can treat arrays as just objects that have their indexes as their keys.

Having our routes configured as follows:

```
const routes: Route[] = [
  { path: 'obj', component: HelloComponent, resolve: { test: ObjectResolver } },
  { path: 'arr', component: HelloComponent, resolve: [ ArrayResolver ] },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/obj' }
];
```

We can observe the following behavior:

[image: The two resolve approaches in action]

Which leads to the conclusion, that even if you provide an array to the `resolve` property of a `Route`, it will be treated "in the same manner".

The difference being in the keys, where if you provide an object, you can define your own keys, and with arrays it just defaults to the index.

Just to be clear, the above is based on messing around with the two ways of providing resolvers, and seeing what happens. Digging into the actual source code could reveal more precise information about the behavior.

I've [created a StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-resolve-obj-array) that contain the above snippets/behavior, feel free to take a look!

Comment: thanks, but in the hello component you are using subscribe. In the tutorial, the activatedRoute and subscribe is not needed

Comment: I've updated the StackBlitz with a non-subscribe approach as well. 

If you try logging `_activatedRoute.data` in the `HelloComponent`, it is a `BehaviorSubject`. Using some typecasting, we can use the `value` property of it, and access the values without subscribing. Not sure what version of Angular they were using in the tutorial, nor what kind of extensions they have set up, that might also be a key difference.

Comment: the idea is you would not have to do anything with activatedRoute in the component.